# convert a string to two dates

Tags: apex, date

Can someone help me in converting a string `'02/02/2016 - 02/10/2016'` into two individual dates?

I want to convert them to start and end date as follows:

- Start Date: 02/02/2016
- End Date: 02/10/2016

Comment: @Anurang A what do you have so far?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're trying to do this in Apex not JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split them using [Split method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split) which can split on the basis of - delimiter

```
String strDate = '02/02/2016 - 02/10/2016';
String [] splitDate = strDate.split('-');
system.debug('*************'+ date.parse(splitDate[0].trim()));
system.debug('*************'+ date.parse(splitDate[1].trim()));
```